# Enable VT-x without going through BIOS

Tags: windows-7, bios, emulator, vt-x

I had set an admin password in bios for security purposes, before setting it, I had disabled VT-x, UEFI booting, and booting from external media.

Unfortunately, I forgot the password, [also it's impossible to reset it without having to replace the board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581854/enabling-intel-virtualization-vt-x-without-option-in-bios)

Now I need to use virtualization software which requires VT-x to be enabled, So there a way to enable VT-x without accessing the BIOS?
.
The method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581854/enabling-intel-virtualization-vt-x-without-option-in-bios) didn't work (also, it's mentioned in one of  the comments that the VT-x should be enabled in the first place for it to work)

While using windows HAXM check tool after following above method, it gave out an error - hardware acceleration needs to be enabled in the BIOS
before committing the blunder, I was using emulators while VT-x was enabled, it was running smoothly.

P.S-Computer specs - Lenovo G470 , i3-2310M @ 2.1Ghz, 6gb RAM,windows 7 64bit model year 2010
please read this [also it's impossible to reset it without having to replace the board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581854/enabling-intel-virtualization-vt-x-without-option-in-bios)

Related [Does VT-x really need bios support?](https://superuser.com/questions/911257/does-vt-x-really-need-bios-support)

Comment: Try removing the CMOS battery for a good 10 minutes and see if that resets the password.  Also check your motherboard or its manual very carefully as many motherboards have a CLRPWD or similar jumper that will remove the password. 
 Depending on make and model of the motherboard there may be a backdoor password into the BIOS to re-enable.

Comment: It is not possible to enable VT-x within an operating system.  **You must enabled it within the firmware.**  It sounds like you will have to perform whatever actions are necessary to remove the password so that is possible.  Most modern laptops don't make that easy, most laptops I have worked with, make it impossible.

Comment: @LawrenceC please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581854/enabling-intel-virtualization-vt-x-without-option-in-bios

Comment: @Moab please read the question completly

Comment: @Ramhound the laptop make year was around 2010, if that helps

Comment: The goal of BIOS password is to prevent you from changing these settings without knowledge of the password.

Comment: setting BIOS password, without keeping backup of it , was by far the one of the biggest mistake of my life :,(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. This is a firmware only setting.

Whether you can retrieve or clear your BIOS password is going to be the determining factor here.